# Cassandra and advanced queries: Spark, ElasticSearch, Sorl

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, apache-spark, sql-like

Ok, so, I'm developing an app and I'm using Cassandra as the database.

Everything going good so far, but now I need to do a query using the LIKE clause.

I know Cassandra doesn't support that, and that's why after looking for a workaround I was thinking in maintaining this single table that I need to query using the LIKE clause in another database, other than Cassandra - was even considering a relational database, even though there wouldn't exist any relations.

Then I started looking to see if this is really the right approach, and came into stuff like Spark, Sorl and ElasticSearch.

Just to make it clear: **I have little to no knowledge about those frameworks.** Really. I only have heard about them and that's all.

So, I'm not here to ask you guys 'hey, how to do that using this framework?'. I just want to know, before I dig into any of those: **Would any of those satisfy my needs?** - Since I have no idea exactly how they work, and what exactly they are for.

If it is the case, them I'll study the framework properly - I just don't want to spend the time to figure out it has nothing to do with my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **elasticsearch** and **solr** fits your needs. They use lucene library to perform reverse indexing and much more -- Datastax enterprise (commercial distribution of Cassandra) offer this solution integrating solr natively. One more solution (little different but working) is to integrate **infinispan** which offers both integration with Cassandra repository and reverse indexing ...

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you go deeper and explain the main differences between both?

Comment: Here you can find a partial answer about infinispan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401828/how-does-apache-cassandra-mash-with-infinispan/25409581#25409581 -- this will explain what is infinispan and how it can be used to achieve the goal